# Decode IrradianceList tag for some pictures using exiftool and XMPtool in Python (Ubuntu)

Tags: python, ubuntu, xmp, exiftool

I am trying to decode the IrradianceList tag for some pictures, here is my code (it is note mine I just use it to try something)..

```
import sys
import os
import glob
import exiftool
import base64
import struct

irradiance_list_tag = 'XMP:IrradianceList'
irradiance_calibration_measurement_golden_tag = 'XMP:IrradianceCalibrationMeasurementGolden'
irradiance_calibration_measurement_tag = 'XMP:IrradianceCalibrationMeasurement'

tags = [ irradiance_list_tag, irradiance_calibration_measurement_tag ]

directory = '/home/stagiaire/Bureau/DATA/'

channels = [ 'RED', 'NIR' ]

index = 0

for channel in channels:
    files = glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, '*' + channel + '*'))
    with exiftool.ExifTool() as et:
        metadata = et.get_tags_batch(tags, files)
        for file_metadata in metadata:
            irradiance_list = file_metadata[irradiance_list_tag]
            irradiance_calibration_measurement = file_metadata[irradiance_calibration_measurement_tag]

            irradiance_list_bytes = base64.b64decode(irradiance_list)

            print(files[index])
            index += 1

            for irradiance_data in struct.iter_unpack("qHHHHfff", irradiance_list_bytes):
                print(irradiance_data)
```

And the Error is in this like

```
irradiance_list = file_metadata[irradiance_list_tag]
```

Here is the error..

```
KeyError: 'XMP:IrradianceList'
```

I beleive the problem is in the installation of XMP tool in Python ?

Comment: > it is note mine I just use it to try something

And yes, that’s the key. You try to play a script kiddie and let others
do your work, and now when it failed you try to make people here on
Stack Overflow to do your work. Get out XMP standard and find out why it
is not working.

Comment: I am not letting others do the work ! I was searching to install exiftool and XMP toolkit all the day for Python, I succeeded for Exiftool but not for XMP toolkit, I am a completely newbie to programming in general so excuse me but I'm trying

Comment: Anyways, thank you f you answer I know that it is betetr to do it by myself I am aware of it. :)

Comment: What I meant is that in order to write this program correctly, there is no way around the fact you have to understand that one crucial piece of information which makes your program worthy of writing (why do you write your program in the first place and not use one already existing? Exactly, because it doesn't exist). If the answer was so simple that people know it here, you wouldn’t have to write that program, most likely.

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer I am still trying to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

```
"""
Code in Python to decode the IrradianceList tag which is an array of the following structure:

  uint64_t timestamp (us)
  uint16_t CH0 (count)
  uint16_t CH1 (count)
  uint16_t gain index
  uint16_t integration time (ms)
  float    yaw
  float    pitch
  float    roll
"""

import sys
import os
import glob
import exiftool
import base64
import struct

irradiance_list_tag = 'XMP:IrradianceList'
irradiance_calibration_measurement_golden_tag = 'XMP:IrradianceCalibrationMeasurementGolden'
irradiance_calibration_measurement_tag = 'XMP:IrradianceCalibrationMeasurement'

tags = [ irradiance_list_tag, irradiance_calibration_measurement_tag ]

directory = 'test'

channels = [ 'RED' ]

index = 0

for channel in channels:
    files = glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, '*' + channel + '*'))
    with exiftool.ExifTool() as et:
        metadata = et.get_tags_batch(tags, files)
        for file_metadata in metadata:
            irradiance_list = file_metadata[irradiance_list_tag]
            irradiance_calibration_measurement = file_metadata[irradiance_calibration_measurement_tag]

            irradiance_list_bytes = base64.b64decode(irradiance_list)

            print(files[index])
            index += 1

        #    for irradiance_data in struct.unpack("qHHHHfff", irradiance_list_bytes):
        #        print(irradiance_data)
        for i in range(0,len(irradiance_list_bytes),28):
            print struct.unpack("qHHHHfff",irradiance_list_bytes[i:i+28])
```